# Accessing variables in JSON from within Azure VM?

Tags: json, powershell, variables, azure, import

I'm using the Azure Powershell command `New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment` together with a JSON template file, and I'm feeding a bunch of parameters to the command that it will use with the JSON file. The JSON also instructs the newly-created VM to download a Powershell script from Azure storage and run it.

I need to pass some values from my Azure Powershell script to that "VM-local" Powershell script. For argument's sake, let's say that my Azure Powershell script has a variable `$foo` with a value of `bar`, representing "the name of a folder to be created on `C:\` (so `C:\bar`)".

How?

How can a script running within the VM access the value `bar` (by any means)? It's fine if I need to use the JSON file as "messenger", or any other necessary trick. I don't think I can modify the "VM-local" Powershell script between downloading it from Azure storage and subsequently running it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the script extension in your JSON template on the VM to run the script, you can specify the entire cmd line for that script.  On that cmd line you would pass parameters just as you would running it interactively.  IOW, think about the cmdline to run that script and that's what you would put into the script extension of the template.

Take a look at this example:

https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/blob/f18a95e857a4caf86b4c2e77e652cec678cd524c/201-vm-winrm-windows/azuredeploy.json

Look at the "commandToExecute" property.  You can see how to invoke powershell.exe with params, the script file being one of those params and then the script file itself also accepts some params through a variable.

You could also do this with DSC (very similar in JSON, but very different PS) but if you already have a PS script you want to use, this should work.

Is that what you needed?

Comment: _"you can specify the entire cmd line for that script"_ Aha! This is something I can understand. And it's so simple, even. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can pass variables like this:

```
New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment -Name ((Get-ChildItem $TemplateFile).BaseName + '-' + ((Get-Date).ToUniversalTime()).ToString('MMdd-HHmm')) `
                            -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName `
                            -TemplateFile $TemplateFile -TemplateParameterObject  @{accountName=$AutomationAccount;moduleName=$Name;moduleURI=$ModuleURI} -Force -Verbose
```

Comment: All right, so that's the "sending" or "external" half. Then, what's the "receiving" or "internal" half; how do I access these variables from (a script running) within the VM? (Note: I just edited my question to include the name and value of an example variable.)

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish exactly? You can't access variables in the JSON that provisioned the VM. If you want to create folders on the VM, you can apply Desired State Configuration (DSC) for example. The DSC script can be configured to create a folder on the VM. Would that solve the problem you're having?

Comment: I am trying to automate creation of machines for sw testing; for that I'll need to set some dynamic names in various software _from a script that runs locally on the VM_. If I could create a plain-text file in the VM with my values (`bar`) then I'd be able to work with that.

Comment: You can indeed do that with DSC. In this case you want to use the File Resource: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/dsc/fileresource

Comment: I don't know what to do with that code snippet (I can't even tell what language it is)... Assuming I know nothing about DSC, and next-to-nothing about Azure, is this doable for a newbie?

Comment: With DSC you can configure that all kinds of resources are available on your provisioned VM. This could not only be useful to copy a file. But for the creation of VM's for sw testing: you could configure that IIS is installed, with a specific version of ASP.NET and much more. You can start your journey here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/automation-dsc-overview/ and a training here: https://mva.microsoft.com/en-us/training-courses/getting-started-with-powershell-desired-state-configuration-dsc--8672?l=ZwHuclG1_2504984382